# Create a slide-in menu similar to Jetpack Joyride on android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to Android development and i am working on a game.

For the main activity you come to when the app launches is going to be a full screen and you touch anywhere to start the game. however, i want the users to be able to access other options like the shop, achievements, profile etc. without being able to start the game and getting the end menu.

The idea i have for the menu is that it slides in from the left, similarly to how Jetpack Joyride slides in from the right, BUT, i want the whole screen to slide across, or the screen slides across uncovering the menu rather than an overlay that slides and covers the main screen.

(this is way advanced coding for someone as new as me, but id still like to know how it can be done)

Comment: This is a very open question.  What platform and language are you using ?

Comment: oh right, specifically starting from API - 15 JellyBean 4.0.3, im working on it in Android Studio